React Native ios build archiving throwing Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code error
Suddenly started getting Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code error while trying to archiving build for IOS after upgrading react-native version to 0.74.4 and Build is running fine on Local.

react native setup info:

I was trying to archive IOS build.

Please do not post pictures of code and instead paste code and error output as formatted text.

I had the same issue and it got fixed when i updated react native version to 0.74.5.
